# How deep can be nesting tuple for choices in django?

Tags: django, django-models, tuples

I have a choice tuple like that

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
                       (DB_ENUMS.GENERAL.EMPTY, 'All'),
                       ('Fashion and style', 
                           (
                           (DB_ENUMS.CATEGORY.FASHION_AND_STYLE, 'All Fashion and Style'),
                               ('Clothes/Shoes', 
                                   (
                                        (1, 'string')
                                   )
                               )
                           )
                       )
                   )
```

But this one

> ((1, 'string'))

is shown on the same level as

> 'All Fashion and Style'

Am I trying to use forbidden things? I found nothing about limits in documentation.

Comment: No hierarchy is allowed in `choices`, it is a simple key<->value matching. You need to implement your own scheme or use a 3rd party tool for this.

Comment: @Selcuk: actually you can use nested/hierachy to display optgroup in choicefield

Comment: @DuD. I stand corrected. I assumed the poster was trying to implement multiple select fields with options changing dependent to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[By default, Django only supports 2 levels of hierarchy in a choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices):

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
            ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
            ('cd', 'CD'),
        )
    ),
    ('Video', (
            ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
            ('dvd', 'DVD'),
        )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)
```

However, there are some third-party apps like [`django-categories`](http://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) that provide the ability to have a hierarchy of choices.